# View file uploaded to SQL content

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have small question that I can't quite figure out solution myself or find any answer (or clue) on web. Let me explain my problem.
I uploaded files to my SQL server using ASP.NET application. 
The thing is, I'd like to view content of those files on aspx page.
Files are only code files (.cs, .aspx etc), basicaly txt in different technologies. I'd also like to use highlight.js to view those files as code.

Comment: You have described your goal, but what is the problem you are having?

Comment: IF you want to view on aspx page, then you need to call them on the aspx page via writing code

Comment: Problem is general word to describe it. I just can't find any solution to achieve my goal, I need a clue where to look for the answer or ideas on how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**UI:**

Import required hightlight required js/css files in .aspx page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.css">
<script src="/path/to/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Have one `label/textarea` to show code of `.aspx/.aspx.cs` file under

```
<pre><code class="cs"><asp:Label id="lblCode" runat="server"/></code><pre>
```

**Server side:**

In `Page_Load()` make db call to get content of .aspx/.aspx.cs files from database and set to label.

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
       this.lblCode=DataAccessLayer.GetCode();
}
```

Check below links for more details about highlight.js

https://highlightjs.org/usage/

http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/css-classes-reference.html

Comment: Thanks for advice, I think I found a way by using File.ReadAllBytes, gonna try few things, and see what I get